# Node and NPM brings our shopsystem to an automatically logout

Tags: node.js, npm, logout

My colleague and I have installed node 10.16.3 and npm 6.11.3 on Mac Mojave, everything is the same.

When I run `npm run build`, our backend pluginfor our shopsystem is working perfectly, *but* when my colleague is running build, the backend is automatically logout, after seconds.

So what can be the problem?

Comment: It's very difficult to answer this question without seeing any code

Comment: Hello :-)
think it has nothing to do with the code, but which part do you need? The plugin is too big to display here.

Comment: You think it has nothing to do with the code but it could be how you initially sessions/cookies. For instance if they’re secure and one of you is running https and the other not. Or if one of you have hardcoded some dB details or urls where sessions are stored and they’re different on another box